# Can I reduce the amount of joins used in this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have a table very similar to the one below, except there are 20 of both the v and p values.

```
|--------------Table 1-------------|
| part_id |   v1 |  v2 |  p1 |  p2 |
|       1 |  250 |   8 |   1 |   2 |
|       2 | 1348 |   9 |  28 |  88 |
|    4094 |  580 | 230 | 207 | 726 |
|    7111 |   12 |  14 | 223 | 195 |
```

I need to join this table with two others, which contain dimension information.

```
|----Values----|    |-------Parameters------|
| v_id | value |    | p_id |    description |
|    8 |     1 |    |    1 | 'Weight (lbs)' |
|     etc...   |    |        etc...         |
```

Current program:

```
proc sql;
    create table table2 as
        select t1.part_id
               ,t1.v1
               ,val.value    
               ,t1.v2
               ,val1.value
               ,t1.p1
               ,par.description
               ,t1.p2
               ,par1.description
        from table_1 t1
        inner join values val
            on val.v_id = t1.v1
        inner join values val1
            on val1.v_id = t1.v2
        inner join parameters par
            on par.p_id = t1.p1
        inner join parameters par1
            on par1.p_id = t1.p2;
quit;
```

Is there a way to join these tables together without using 40 inner joins?

Comment: Are you open to not using SQL at all? Create a format from the values/parameter data set and then use an array within a data set to loop through and create the descriptions you need.

Comment: You should consider in improving your design instead of creating a query to do this amount of joins. A table like table1_value_parameter would be a nicer design.

Comment: @Reeza Yes, I am open to not using SQL at all. I will look into your suggestion.

Comment: @JorgeCampos These three tables weren't created by me, so I don't really have that option.

Comment: yes you can. Use pivot/unpivot clause. BTW EAV is sql-antipattern,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a format from the values/parameter data set and then use an array within a data set to loop through and create the descriptions you need. Here's a sample for the parameter table that should get you started. I haven't tested this code though :).

```
data param_fmt;
fmtname='param_fmt';
start=p_id;
label=value;
run;


proc format cntlin=param_fmt;
run;



data want;
set have;

array p(*) p1-p3;
array p_desc(*) p_desc1-p_desc3;

do i=1 to dim(p);
p_desc(i) = put(p(i), param_fmt.);
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Reeza. I was able to create formats for both and get the desired final result.

Answer (score 2):

### Formats

If your dimension tables are simple and small then convert them into formats.

```
data cntlin ;
  set values ;
  by v_id;
  retain fmtname 'VALUES';
  rename v_id = start value = label;
run;
proc format cntlin=cntlin;
run;
```

Then you do not even need to modify your input table. You can use it as is and just attach the formats to have the values or descriptions printed instead of the ids.

```
 proc print data=table_1 ;
   format v1-v2 values. p1-p2 parameters. ;
 run;
```

If your dimension tables have more than two columns then turn each extra column into another format.

### Lookup

If the dimensions are too large for a format, then try using the KEY= option on set statements to lookup the dimension values.

```
data want ;
  set table_1 ; 
  array _v v1-v2 ;
  array _p p1-p2 ;
  array values(2) ;
  array descriptions (2) $50 ;
  do _n_=1 to dim(_v);
     v_id=_v(_n_) ;
     if not (missing(v_id)) then set values key=v_id;
     values(_n_) = value ;
     p_id=_p(_n_) ;
     if not (missing(p_id)) then set parameters key=p_id;
     parameters(_n_) = parameter ;
     output;
     call missing(of value parameter);
  end;
```

### Transform

You could also transform your TABLE_1 to a tall instead of a wide format. Then you do not need so many joins.

```
data tall ;
  set table_1 ;
  array _v v1-v2 ;
  array _p p1-p2 ;
  do col=1 to dim(_v);
     v_id=_v(col) ;
     p_id=_p(col) ;
     output;
  end;
  drop v1-v2 p1-p2 ;
run;
proc sql ;
  create table_2 as 
    select a.*
         , v.value
         , p.description
    from tall a
    left join values v on a.v_id = v.v_id
    left join parameters p on a.p_id = p.description
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ugh, what a horrible design to have to work with! I assume you're stuck with this? If so, you have my sincerest sympathy. If not, change it if you can!

Anyway, since you have a fixed number of each type of column (8, you said), you could always try unpivoting your table into one value/parameter id column, doing the join and then repivoting into single rows, like so:

```
with table1 as (select 1 part_id, 250 v1, 8 v2, 1 p1, 2 p2 from dual union all
                select 2 part_id, 1348 v1, 9 v2, 28 p1, 88 p2 from dual union all
                select 4094 part_id, 580 v1, 230 v2, 207 p1, 726 p2 from dual union all
                select 7111 part_id, 12 v1, 14 v2, 223 p1, 195 p2 from dual),
       vals as (select 250 v_id, 1 value from dual union all
                select 1348 v_id, 2 value from dual union all
                select 580 v_id, 3 value from dual union all
                select 12 v_id, 4 value from dual union all
                select 8 v_id, 5 value from dual union all
                select 9 v_id, 6 value from dual union all
                select 230 v_id, 7 value from dual union all
                select 14 v_id, 8 value from dual),
     params as (select 1 p_id, 'Weight (lbs)' description from dual union all
                select 28 p_id, 'Weight (kgs)' description from dual union all
                select 207 p_id, 'Length (ins)' description from dual union all
                select 223 p_id, 'Length (cm)' description from dual union all
                select 2 p_id, 'Time (secs)' description from dual union all
                select 88 p_id, 'Time (mins)' description from dual union all
                select 726 p_id, 'Speed (mph)' description from dual union all
                select 195 p_id, 'Speed (kmph)' description from dual),
         t1 as (select part_id,
                       id,
                       v_id,
                       p_id
                from   table1
                unpivot ((v_id, p_id) for id in ((v1, p1) as 1,
                                                 (v2, p2) as 2))),
        res as (select t1.part_id,
                       t1.id,
                       t1.v_id,
                       v.value,
                       t1.p_id,
                       p.description
                from   t1
                       inner join vals v on t1.v_id = v.v_id
                       inner join params p on t1.p_id = p.p_id)
select part_id,
       "1_V" v1,
       "1_VAL" val1,
       "2_V" v2,
       "2_VAL" val2,
       "1_P" p1,
       "1_DESCR" descr1,
       "2_P" p2,
       "2_DESCR" descr2
from   res
pivot (max(v_id) as v,
       max(value) as val,
       max(p_id) as p,
       max(description) as descr
       for id in (1, 2));

   PART_ID         V1       VAL1         V2       VAL2         P1 DESCR1               P2 DESCR2      
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ------------
         1        250          1          8          5          1 Weight (lbs)          2 Time (secs) 
         2       1348          2          9          6         28 Weight (kgs)         88 Time (mins) 
      4094        580          3        230          7        207 Length (ins)        726 Speed (mph) 
      7111         12          4         14          8        223 Length (cm)         195 Speed (kmph)
```

Another alternative, which may be better if you have lots of repeated ids (so that you can take advantage of subquery caching) is to simply put the subqueries in the select list, like so:

```
with table1 as (select 1 part_id, 250 v1, 8 v2, 1 p1, 2 p2 from dual union all
                select 2 part_id, 1348 v1, 9 v2, 28 p1, 88 p2 from dual union all
                select 4094 part_id, 580 v1, 230 v2, 207 p1, 726 p2 from dual union all
                select 7111 part_id, 12 v1, 14 v2, 223 p1, 195 p2 from dual),
       vals as (select 250 v_id, 1 value from dual union all
                select 1348 v_id, 2 value from dual union all
                select 580 v_id, 3 value from dual union all
                select 12 v_id, 4 value from dual union all
                select 8 v_id, 5 value from dual union all
                select 9 v_id, 6 value from dual union all
                select 230 v_id, 7 value from dual union all
                select 14 v_id, 8 value from dual),
     params as (select 1 p_id, 'Weight (lbs)' description from dual union all
                select 28 p_id, 'Weight (kgs)' description from dual union all
                select 207 p_id, 'Length (ins)' description from dual union all
                select 223 p_id, 'Length (cm)' description from dual union all
                select 2 p_id, 'Time (secs)' description from dual union all
                select 88 p_id, 'Time (mins)' description from dual union all
                select 726 p_id, 'Speed (mph)' description from dual union all
                select 195 p_id, 'Speed (kmph)' description from dual)
select t1.part_id,
       t1.v1,
       (select value from vals v where v.v_id = t1.v1) val1,
       t1.v2 v2,
       (select value from vals v where v.v_id = t1.v2) val2,
       t1.p1 p1,
       (select description from params p where p.p_id = t1.p1) descr1,
       t1.p2 p2,
       (select description from params p where p.p_id = t1.p2) descr2
from   table1 t1;

   PART_ID         V1       VAL1         V2       VAL2         P1 DESCR1               P2 DESCR2      
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ------------
         1        250          1          8          5          1 Weight (lbs)          2 Time (secs) 
         2       1348          2          9          6         28 Weight (kgs)         88 Time (mins) 
      4094        580          3        230          7        207 Length (ins)        726 Speed (mph) 
      7111         12          4         14          8        223 Length (cm)         195 Speed (kmph)
```

Which would work better for you depends entirely on your dataset. As always, you should test each solution thoroughly!